# What does Trump hope to achieve by calling the Swedish prime minister about ASAP Rocky?

Tags: united-states, donald-trump, international-relations, sweden

There has been some media discussion on Trump's recent statement that he is going to call the Swedish prime minister, Stefan Löfven, about the fact that US rapper [ASAP Rocky](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASAP_Rocky) is currently being held in Swedish legal custody.

Short of being told how the Swedish legal system works, which surely Trump has access to people much closer to him who could tell him and which certainly doesn't require direct communication between heads of government, given that Swedish ministers or the Swedish parliament cannot intervene in a criminal investigation, what would be the purpose of such a phone call? What would Trump hope to accomplish by making such a phone call?

Answers would ideally discuss both national and international aspects.

Comment: Since when is a tweet a statement?

Comment: @gnasher729 Why wouldn't a tweet be a statement? Trumps tweets specifically are [considered](http://www.lawjournalnewsletters.com/sites/lawjournalnewsletters/2017/12/01/trumps-tweets-are-official-statements/) official [statements](https://twitter.com/CNN/status/872163870143655936).

Comment: He may believe that the Swedish PM has pardon powers similar to his own, which could be used to stop the prosecution.

Answer (score 2):

He hopes to accomplish nothing in Sweden.

He hopes to accomplish a lot in the U.S., by elevating Kanye West in the political sphere and strengthening their bond of friendship.

In turn, Kanye West will continue trying to help Trump win more support among his fans, which includes black and young people, two important voting blocks.

(Of course, the question is speculative in nature, as it asks about a person's thought process. So my answer is speculative, as well.)

Comment: But it seems as though by elevating West and/or supporting rappers, he would risk alienating a large part of his existing supporters.  (Or course this assumes he's thinking logically...)

Comment: Why would supporting West or other rappers alienate a large part of his base? I don't see the correlation. Trump voters care more about his policies than his asinine tweets (many of which are probably designed solely to troll his critics). @jamesqf

Comment: It's unclear how Trump's tweets can be both able to gain him new voters but not able to lose his current ones.  At the very least some people may regret voting for a troll.

Comment: @EricNolan, *"It's unclear how Trump's tweets can be both able to gain him new voters but not able to lose his current ones."* … Everything a president does has the potential to win new voters and lose existing ones.

Comment: @Michael_B: Because most Trump supporters probably consider rappers to be the scum of the Earth, and would gladly see them all immured in foreign jails :-)  And would certainly object having the US President try to get them preferrential treatment.  (Even I, who am far from being a Trump supporter, would object to that.  The person should be treated like anyone else.)

Comment: @Michael_B two important voting blocks that are typically voting for Democrats one might add.